# Can I run mod_dav_svn and svnserve on the same server

Tags: svn, svnserve, mod-dav-svn

I need to expose our subversion repo over http / https, as I'm having trouble getting maven and subversion to play over svn+ssh. The real issue is a corporate restriction whereby we're not allowed a generic unix account (so that maven could svn+ssh without using an personal user account). My intention was to use maven with this generic account to perform branch and release functions. I can do this over http as I can then set up a local .htaccess style account to authenticate maven.

My question is if there are any concerns or gotchas I need to be aware of when having some users committing over http and some via svn+ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if there are any concerns or gotchas I need to be aware

No. Just use the same folder for `SVNParentPath` in Apache and for `-r` of svnserve (for simplicity - same hotname, only protocol will differ)

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a repository using different protocols will work, but in my experience using mod_dav_svn for all user access has many advantages:

- no user account for SVN access required, use LDAP, and/or "basic" authentication instead,
- easy tool integration through HTTP(S) transport
- powerful Apache integration (mod_rewrite, mod_proxy_http...)
- supports modeling project roles, individually, or with groups, and if necessary on a directory basis,
- audit friendly access rule storage *in* a repository (file: method), or in *the* repository (^ method).

Using multiple  blocks for the same repository parent directory will work, too.